# Is $ \sum_{n=1}\limits^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sinh(2^{n})} $ equal to $ \frac{2}{e^{2}-1}$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, hyperbolic-functions

Show that
$$ \sum\limits_{n=1}\limits^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sinh(2^{n})}= \frac{2}{e^{2}-1}. $$

Comment: I'll conjecture that it is $\dfrac 2{e^2-1}$.

Comment: Writing $\sinh$ in terms of $\exp$ and separating into partial fractions might be one way to go about computing the sum.

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+1%2Fsinh%282%5En%29+from+n%3D1+to+infinity http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=0.313035285499331036+closed+form

Comment: @Dr.MV: well the first $1000$ digits are right (and probably many more)

Comment: how to obtain the $ \frac{2}{e^{2}-1}$?

Comment: No problem @Dr.MV! Now we need a proof, good luck!

Comment: Yes.  All the luck we need.  This has got to have an easy way forward.

Comment: @HamedBaghalGhaffari "my conjecture is ..." tit's a bit dishonest

Comment: @JeSuis a "new conjecture"

Comment: This is [AMM Problem 11853](http://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/10.4169/amer.math.monthly.122.7.700.pdf?acceptTC=true). Per our contest policy, I'm locking this question until the contest is over.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{\sinh(2^n)} = 2\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{e^{2^n}-e^{-2^n}} = 2\sum_{n\geq 1}\left(e^{-2^n}+e^{-3\cdot 2^n}+e^{-5\cdot 2^n}+\ldots\right)$$
and since every even integer number $m\geq 1$ can be written in a unique way as the product of a power of two and an odd number, the last series equals:
$$ 2\sum_{m\geq 1}e^{-2m} = \frac{2}{e^2-1} $$
as conjectured.

Comment: how do you write the third equality?

Comment: +1: Thanks for the quick answer. More generally we have $$\sum_{n\geq 1}\dfrac{1}{\sinh(2^n\, x)}=\dfrac 2{e^{2x}-1}$$

Comment: @Dr.MV: it is just the fundamental theorem of arithmetic.